# How to know which driver is missing from hp laptop?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, hp-pavilion

I have an hp pavilion g6, windows 7 64 bit, many drivers are missing like the sleep mode, and if use hybrid mode or lock mode, the laptop freezes and i have to restart it.

The Bluetooth drivers were missing but i managed to solve it because the users on this site helped me.

I don't want to ask you guys to solve all the problems, if you could just tell me how to know which driver is missing then i could look it up by myself.

HP support assistant didn't find any updates for my drivers. HP driver checker tool on their website wasn't able to locate my pc. I tried using the product name and number, didn't find it.

So how to know if a driver is missing so i could download it? Detecting that the Bluetooth driver is missing is easy, but for example how to know if an hd graphic card driver is missing?

Comment: Check Device Manager, do you see a yellow ! for any device?

Comment: @Karan I see `standard vga graphics adapter` that's the only one with a yellow sign on it

Comment: @Ramhound issues like what?

Comment: @Fischer - What sort of graphics card do you have?  The fact you don't have a valid display driver could explain the sleep and hybrid issues, but there are not drivers, for those features.

Comment: If you have no idea what graphics card you have, you can use something like [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/GPU-Z/), [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) etc.

Comment: @Ramhound i have an `intel hd graphics 3000` card

Comment: @Karan thanks for the suggestion! i use gpu-z and cpu-z :)

Comment: Search the HP support site using your PC model or serial number or service tag or whatever they want, then check the list of drivers for your OS. If push comes to shove and there are no drivers provided by your PC manufacturer, you can check the device manufacturer's site (in this case Intel) for generic drivers that may work just as well or maybe even better. Last resort if you can't even identify an unknown device is to use the PCI ID database (it's been discussed in previous answers) and locate the drivers (even those for the same device provided by a different PC manufacturer might work).

Comment: @Ramhound I wouldn't be surprised that sleep/hybrid/suspend aren't working if he doesn't have the proper ACPI drivers for the chipset.

Comment: @DarthAndroid - I suppose.  I got the impression he installed every driver he could find for his laptop already.

Comment: @Karan thanks, i found a driver at intel.com and i am downloading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to know which one is explicitly *missing*; However, I've yet to find a major laptop or motherboard manufacturer which provides all their drivers organized by product.

[Here is the driver download page for hp pavilion g6, windows 7 64 bit](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5078476).

I usually just install all of the most recent versions of each of the drivers they list. There are a few things you have to watch for, like don't install the ATI graphics drivers if you don't have an ATI GPU, don't install the nvidia drivers if you don't have an nvidia GPU, etc.

Comment: thanks, i'll try doing that, although i think that i have some of these drivers already installed. you know what i'lll try to download everything i see on that page, like you said, i wish they included all the drivers in an iso file, like linux distros, for example i downloaded all the debian drivers for crunchbang in one big iso file. I think this issue is solved thought i'm not sure, still downloading all the drivers... i'll accept the answer and if i have any issue i'll come back... thank you all!

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues with installing the same driver multiple times; The driver installer will either uninstall the old driver, or Windows will simply not use the older version. (I'm sure there is some obscure hardware vendor that will make me a liar, but for all the major vendors, this works.)

Comment: true, i tried installing some drivers, the new ones were installed like my vga driver, if my driver is the same version i got a message saying "this driver already installed, do you want to reinstall it" and when installing an older driver, i also got a warning message, and my issue is solved btw